# Issue finding and using lib folder in Nuget package C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am working on creating a sample Nuget package to test out the process of creating an internal Nuget package for use in another project of mine. My end goal is to create a simple Nuget package, which can be installed onto another simple C# project, and tested out.

I have been following the Microsoft tutorial to create & publish a package using VS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework

I successfully created & published my package on **nuget.org**, called `MyNugetPackage`, and attempted to install it onto my **other** C# project called `TestingMyNugetPackage`. I received an error in the NuGet package console stating:

> Package does not support any target framework

This error makes sense, because I had read about supporting multiple `.NET` versions and specifying the version under the `lib` folder, and I definitely **did not** do that when creating my package:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks

This idea of `lib` folder makes sense to me and I think I understand how to add my target `.NET` version to it. However, *I cannot find this folder anywhere*! It's not anywhere in the C# project directory. I assume I may need to create it on my own, but I'm not sure where to put it.

Many tutorials and SO questions I have read about this topic talk about **how** to use the `lib` folder, but no one ever says where it is. I'm a complete beginner to this and I know I am missing something obvious here, but I'm not sure what it is.

**Edit**: I did try to change my `.nupkg` file to a `.zip` file and extracting the contents in attempt to view the `lib` folder. This did work in extracting the contents, but I did not see any `lib` folder after expanding entire project tree and searching for `lib`.

Here is a quick layout of my C# solution tree:

Solution titled `MyNugetPackage` with a `MyNugetPackage.sln` file, a `MyNugetPackage.csproj` file, and a simple class `Logger.cs` that just has a `public void Print(string text) { Console.WriteLine(text); }` method:

```
MyNugetPackage
    MyNugetPackage.csproj.1.0.0.nupkg
    MyNugetPackage.nuspec
    MyNugetPackage.sln
    MyNugetPackage (folder)

        bin (folder)
            Debug (folder) -> .dll, .pdb
            Release (folder) -> .dll, .pdb

        obj (folder)
            Debug (folder)
            Release (folder)

        Properties (folder)
            AssemblyInfo.cs

        Logger.cs
        MyNugetPackage.csproj
```

Could someone direct me where I need to place my `lib` folder, so that I can add my supported `.NET 4.7` framework reference, and successfully install my package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NuGet package (.nupkg) is just a zip file. If you are trying to view the contents of this file, open it like a zip file (using 7zip or something). Alternatively change the extension to zip. In the package you will find the "lib" folder as well as the .nuspec, and package folder (among other contents). But this is the resulting package that is built when you Pack your project, changes here would have no affect on your code.

If you're just trying to target one or more frameworks. In VS, edit your project file (.csproj). This file is an XML with a PropertyGroup that contains either a "TargetFramework" **OR** a "TargetFrameworks" element. To target a single framework add a TargetFramework element, to target multiple use the TragetFrameworks instead.

To target a single .Net framework:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Alternatively, you can target multiple frameworks.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472; netcoreapp3.0; netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This would target .Net 4.7.2, .Net Core 3.0, and .Net Core 2.1

Comment: So I followed the instructions about extracting the .zip file contents, and I did see most of the familiar items from my project, in addition to extra `_rels` folder and `.signature`. file. But there is no `lib` folder in here, and I have expanded all folders. I have modified my `.csproj` and added the `TargetFramework` line, I am going to push a new version of my package and see if that resolves my error.

Comment: My lib folder only contains the framework(s) defined in the project file. The lib folder just has files for that target.

Comment: Your solution of adding `<PropertyGroup> and <TargetFramework>` XML resolved my installation issue. I updated the `.csproj` like you mentioned, and added `net472`. I re-created my `.nuspec` and `.nupkg` files, pushed the new `.nupkg` to nuget.org once again (not sure if I even needed to do this), then re-downloaded the `.nupkg` (probably redundant step), and ran `Install-Package C:\Path\To\My\package.nupkg`, where the package was successfully installed. This resolved my issue of "Package does not support any target framework"